# In LaTeX, how to escape to print out a block of text

Tags: latex

The Problem: I just want to print a sequence like this in plain text:

```
                     a (10)
                   _/ \_
                  /     \
             (4) b       c (4)
               _/ \___
              /       \
         (8) d       _ e _ (5)
            / \     /  |  \
           f   g   h   i   j
          (2) (4) (1) (1) (6)
```

I would like to avoid escaping all characters along the way, including special characters for preserving spaces. Essentially, I am drawing an ASCII picture!

Comment: Have you looked at the existing questions on http://tex.stackexchange.com ? Please consider moving your question there - it's a much better fit

Answer (score 15):

For a pure ASCII-picture interpretation, use the `verbatim` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
             a (10)
           _/ \_
          /     \
     (4) b       c (4)
       _/ \___
      /       \
 (8) d       _ e _ (5)
    / \     /  |  \
   f   g   h   i   j
  (2) (4) (1) (1) (6)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The `verbatim` environment sets interprets spaces, line breaks and special characters as-is.